# Input field works good on web and iPhone but not on android

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, react-hooks, client

Added my code, this is the input field
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny8VS.png)

```
 <div
        ref={ref}
        className={classes.part}
        onKeyDown={disabled ? undefined : handleKeyDown}
        onClick={disabled ? undefined : handleClick}
        tabIndex={disabled ? undefined : 0}
    >
        <input
            type='text'
            value={isUndefined(value) ? '--' : pad(value, 2)}
            disabled={disabled}
            className={classnames(classes.partInput, isCalendar ? classes.partCalendar : classes.partTime)}
        />
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. Please, post your code in text instead of an image for more visibility

Comment: Since you are referring to react-hooks, it would be great to have handleKeyDown and handleClick too, as they could be the potential source of the problem. Also is there a specific reason to why you are not using the onChange event from the input?

Comment: @Nestoro try to change handleKeyDown and handleClick to the input but not help

Comment: @Nestoro change function I can't move from the parent component